# Implementing a multiplication-counting function

Tags: haskell

I have written this:

```
pow :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
pow x k = if k == 1
then x
else if k `mod` 2 == 0
then pow (x*x) (k `div` 2)
else x * pow (x*x) (k `div` 2)
```

Now I want to write a program which has a given `k` and decides how many multiplications `pow x k` is going to execute.

My idea was:

```
costpow :: Integer -> Integer
costpow 1 = 0
costpow k = if m == 0 
then   1 + costpow k
else  2 + costpow k
where ( n , m ) = k `divMod` 2
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of what `costpow k` is supposed to return for a few sample values of `k`? (`costpow 2`, `costpow 3`, `costpow 4`, for example.)

Answer (score 2):

This is an infinite loop:

```
costpow k = ...
   ... 1 + costpow k
                   ^^^
```

You probably want something like `1 + costpow n` instead.

Comment: Yes but i don't know how to write it.  If i have a given k then it is also a infinite loop ?

Comment: The trick to recursion is to build off of a smaller result in your recursive function. I.e. `costpow k` should generally not depend on `costpow k`, but on `costpow x` run on some `x < k`, for it to terminate. Often we use `x = k - 1`, but it's not always that simple, and it's not in this case. Look at the definition of `pow` you've written – what definition of `x` does it pick at each step when calling `pow x`, and how does it relate to `k`? Should you use the same choice when calling `costpow` recursively or not?...

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion will never end as stated in the other post.  Perhaps you can simplify a little more

```
costpow :: Integer -> Integer
costpow 1 = 0
costpow k = m + 1 + costpow n
       where (n,m) = k `divMod` 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the resolve, but I have to look it up more detailed, because i didn't understand it really.